# How to find child tag according to class information or id information?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, request

I have an HTML page source.

I am trying to find the all tag `p` that is a child of a tag that has id `storytext`.

I guess it will use `find` function, but I am not sure how to do it.

Now I am using

```
b = source_page.find(".story, {"id": "storytext"}", first=False)
```

However, it does not work.

I am using `AsyncHTMLSession` from `requests_html`.
Or is it possible to do it in `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: `source_page.select('#storytext p')`

Answer (score 1):

What about using JQuery selector like below

```
//This will get all P tags inside the tag with Id "storytext"

$("#storytext p")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got the hint that using ```#``` to represent id. It is solve now.